# Finding an attribute in an XML file using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have this XML file, and I would like to find the `lektion_lexi_margin` value. The only thing known about the value is the attribute `thessi`. How can I accomplish that?

I tried the following code without success

```
margin_left = $("[thessi$="+Pc+"]").attr("lektion_lexi_margin");

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lektionen>
    <Lektion>
        <lektion></lektion>
        <lektion_buch>Arbeitsbuch</lektion_buch>
        <lektion_frage_text_ap view="" typ="" thessi=""></lektion_frage_text_ap>
        <lektion_photo thessi=""></lektion_photo>
        <lektion_teil></lektion_teil>
        <lektion_title></lektion_title>
        <lektion_bearbeitung>
            <lektion_ap thessi="1" lektion_lexi_margin="7">was</lektion_ap>
            <lektion_ap thessi="3" lektion_lexi_margin="10">das</lektion_ap>
        </lektion_bearbeitung>
    </Lektion>
</lektionen>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$.each($(xml).find('lektion_ap'),function(){
    alert($(this).attr('lektion_lexi_margin'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lfrias/YgVA5/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('xml lektion_ap').each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('lektion_lexi_margin'));
});
```